# javascript: match method returning object instead of Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, match

I have following piece of code:

```
var completename = file.name;
var regex = '/-\w+_/';
var filenameTest_components = completename.match(/-\w+_/);
console.log(completename);
console.log(typeof filenameTest_components, filenameTest_components)
```

I intend to use the first two elements of the array filenameTest_components however, it gives me error when i try to print first element of the array:

```
console.log(filenameTest_components[1])

TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null
```

WIth this error i am confused if match method should return `array` or an `object`?

SO the current output if i print only input string and match output looks like as follows:

```
task-routelearning_events.json
object [ '-routelearning_',
  index: 4,
  input: 'task-routelearning_events.json' ]
```

Edit:

To give  a larger picture following is the link to github

https://github.com/suyashdb/bids-validator/blob/illegal_Character_underscoreInTaskname/validators/bids.js#L128

Comment: Also null is of type object, which can be confusing

Comment: `null` is `object` but its not. I can't even understand what im saying

Comment: OK so this is confusing as well. Arrays are key/value objects with keys starting from 0. If you console.log(filenameTest_components['index']) it should output 4. Technically the output could say [0: '-routelearning_', ...]. Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec for more info

Comment: I would recommend reading https://blog.simpleblend.net/is-everything-in-javascript-an-object/ It explains JS types or lack there of.

Comment: ```/Users/admin/Desktop/git_bids-validator/illegal_character/bids-validator/validators/bids.js:163
                var result = filenameTest_components.map(function(filenameTest_component){return filenameTest_component;});
                                                    ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null ```

Answer (score 2):

`String.prototype.match()` always returns an array when there is a match (`null` otherwise), but as you may know, arrays are objects in JavaScript. If you use `typeof` on an array, you will get `object` (`typeof null` also returns `object`). So the best way to determine if you have an array or not is to use `Array.isArray()`.

```js
var str = 'foo bar baz foo',
    res = str.match(/foo/g);

console.log(res); // ["foo", "foo"]
console.log(typeof res); // object
console.log(Array.isArray(res)); // true
```

Comment: I see. Than how can i get first element of the array output from match method

Comment: Something like this: `arr[0]`. Don't forget that the first index of an array is 0, not 1...

Comment: exactly thats the issue. arr[0] returns nothing but an error.

Comment: Use `console.log(arr)` and tell me what you get. I suspect the problem is with your regex...

Comment: I am getting:
```task-routelearning_events.json
object [ '-routelearning_',
  index: 4,
  input: 'task-routelearning_events.json' ]```

Comment: This is not an array. Could you provide the value of `completename`?

Comment: I tested your code in a JSFiddle and it works fine... It returns an array with only one string. `filenameTest_components[0]` gives `-routelearning_`.

Comment: Edit your question and put **exactly** what you are doing. Currently, it is impossible to diagnose your problem...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144702/discussion-between-learnningprogramming-and-badacadabra).

Answer (score 1):

It returns an array if there was a match or null if not

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

Comment: there is a match and when i print it does looks like array but i am able to print first element ..

Answer (score 0):

Javascript match function returns the matches as an Array object.

In case you want to use returned value from match function, you have to convert it to Array

```
var result = filenameTest_components.map(el => el);
console.log(result[0]);
```

Comment: what does `el=>el` stands for ?

Comment: Sorry, it's my mistake. I did not check it carefully. 
I think it caused by your regex.

`el => el` stands for each element in `filenameTest_components` array. 
This is ES6 arrow functions, please check below link for more details: 

http://es6-features.org/#ExpressionBodies